# Airflow api to stop a dag run

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I want to control airflow DAG runs using my python code base. There is a start DAG api `POST /api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/dag_runs`

But want to know if there is any stop DAG api which can just mark all the task failed/abort for that particular DAG

Comment: is there any api to mark a complete dag run failed/sucess ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pause it using /api/experimental/dags//paused/ with boolean value.

Stopping a DAG is not available at this point in the experimental Rest API.

UPDATE: There is something called _set_dag_run_state with paramers (dag_id, execution_date, state, session=None) with in mark_dags API.

Also, you could use set_dag_run_state_to_failed to mark a dag as failed and set_dag_run_state_to_running to mark a dag as a success. But I'm not quite sure what it's routeing could be.

Comment: thanks @Anup. is there any api to mark a dag run failed/sucess ?

Comment: There is something called _set_dag_run_state with paramers (dag_id, execution_date, state, session=None) with in mark_dags. Also, you could use set_dag_run_state_to_failed and set_dag_run_state_to_running. Will update the answer.

Comment: mark_dags API doesn't seem to be exposed with a REST endpoint https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/www/api/experimental/endpoints.py